# Configure Colours and/or Macros on Razer Mamba WITHOUT Synapse?

Tags: drivers, razer-mouse, razer-synapse

Just wondering if it's at all possible to configure the macros and especially the colours/lighting on a Razer Mamba mouse without using the Synapse software.

Can anyone think of a way to manually alter any configuration files to configure the mouse that way?

Or does anyone have access to config files/xml files/whatever that would configure the mouse in a specific manner, available for download?

I don't want to connect this computer to the internet even once (I'm aware after registration the mouse can be set to run in Offline Mode).